# How do I show the labels of theorems, definitions, etc

Tags: theorems, showlabels

I'm using the package `showlabels` which has the effect that when I label something with `\label{thing1}` the `thing1` gets typeset in the margin of my document next to where I put the label. This works fine for equations in `align` and `proof` environments, and things like that.

The problem is that it does not work when I label a theorem, which I do like this:

```
\begin{theorem}\label{fact1}
Important math statement.
\end{theorem}
```

I can still refer to said theorem via `\ref{fact1}`
but I cannot get the label to typeset in the margin next to the theorem.

**EDIT:**
I originally failed to include a compilable example of the problem. @DavidCarlisle posted an example of the problem *not* occurring, but with `showlabels` replaced with `showkeys`, upon which I noticed that `showkeys` did not produce the problem.

Looking more closely at my preamble, the problem had to do with the `hyperref` package. The following does not result in the label on the theorem being displayed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{a theorem}
    Important math statement.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if one moves the hyperref package so it is implemented before showlabels, as follows, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{a theorem}
    Important math statement.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a complete compilable example?

Comment: This made me realize that I probably would have answered my own question before posting if I'd made the minimal example first. This is probably obvious to many, but from now on I'm going to do that as a rule.

Comment: Your observation about the orders of hyperref and showlabels is very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With showlabels

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Zzzz}
zzz

\begin{theorem}\label{fact1}
Important math statement.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or with showkeys

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Zzzz}
zzz

\begin{theorem}\label{fact1}
Important math statement.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much! I want to include that when adding 'showkeys' I had to remove 'showlabels' to avoid equations getting 2 overlapping labels. But this was not a problem because showkeys gave exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @j0equ1nn `showkeys` and `showlabels` are designed to do exactly the same thing, just using slightly different code, loading both would be strange to say the least

Comment: That makes sense, though for some reason in my case the labels shown by showlabels is a proper subset of the labels shown by showkeys. This probably has to do with the other packages I used, which I failed to include. Nonetheless this does the trick!

Comment: @j0equ1nn but your comment made me realize I had answered with one package when you had used another. Either work I've changed the answer to show both forms.

Comment: Weird.. Well, although switching to showkeys resolved my issue, for the benefit of others let me try to find a minimal example of the issue I experienced and I will edit the question to include it.

Comment: What if you only want to `showlabels` sometimes?

Comment: @information_interchange I suppose you could save the original `\label` before loading the package and then use that if you don't want it shown, but why would you want that? a document is either the final form or it isn't and why does it matter in drafts if you have some labels showing that you do not need?